# Cordova iOS play localy stored video file

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, video

I have an Angular 2 Cordova application that's flushed out for Android now I'm working on iOS conversion.

I have a video component that allows streaming or optionally downloading the video to watch later.  I have streaming working using video tag. I got it to work using video src rather then the source child element which didn't work.

```
<video width="100%" src="https://path/to/source.mp4" controls></video>
```

For some reason though it won't play local files, either with path type cdv/file.  I'm using cordova-plugin-file to store the video file and it's working fine. I navigated to the /Documents folder for the app with a separate tool and found the video was stored correctly and plays fine on my machine.

```
cdv://
file:///
```

So really the last step is why the browser isn't playing the file?  is it preventing the url? do I need to use a relative path and if so how do I get to /Documents folder? from www/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using cordova.file

If i use

```
cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory
```

I get a path with an ID, which I assume is the application ID.  Well what I failed to realize is that every time the application is built using xCode it creates a new ID.

So when I was hardcoding in the file url to the video tag, i was using an old ID.  By use the cordova.file path it has the right ID every time and consequently the correct root path.

Comment: And for android should be "this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory". Otherwise wont play local files